# Python class (input name,output number)

Tags: python

i want to create code which will be outputing the sum of the product prize. Example below.

```
Input:
bread,rice

Output:
6,5 $
```

Here is my code:

```
class product:
def __init__(self,name,color,prize)
    self.name=name
    self.color=color
    self.prize=prize
def info(self)
    input(name)
    return (self.prize) 
tomato=product()
tomato.name="tomato"
tomato.color="czerwony"
tomato.prize= 4,56
 
turnip=product()
turnip.name="turnip"
turnip.color="white"
turnip.prize= 5.65
 


print("write the name of one products from the list and I will tell you how much it costs [tomato,turnip] "
info()
```

There is only 2 products,i wanted to reduce code lines.

Comment: Okay. Did you try any code to find the sum? Do you have any more specific question than "how do I do this?" ? What do you think are the logical steps to solving the problem?

Comment: i have no idea how can I sum up values assigned to objects

Comment: Well, can you find the object? can you get the desired attribute? Can you do sums?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this, please note, the code below does not have any error/validation checks in place:

```
class product:
    def __init__(self,name=None,color=None,prize=None):
            self.name=name
            self.color=color
            self.prize=prize
    def info(self):
            return (self.prize)
tomato=product()
tomato.name="tomato"
tomato.color="czerwony"
tomato.prize= 4.56

turnip=product()
turnip.name="turnip"
turnip.color="white"
turnip.prize= 5.65


user_input = raw_input("write the name of one products from the list and I will tell you how much it costs [tomato,turnip]:")

print(eval(user_input).info())
```